# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when an NSMenuItem's target/selector is set to an object

Tags: swift, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I'm abstracting the NSMenuItem using this class:

```
class MenuItem{
    let title: String
    let iconName: String
    let action: Action
    init(title: String, iconName: String, _ action: @escaping Action) {
        self.title = title
        self.iconName = iconName
        self.action = action
    }

    @objc func doAction(sender: NSMenuItem){
        action()
    }
}
```

And here's the static function that builds the menu:

```
static func getMenu(items: [MenuItem]) -> NSMenu{
    let m = NSMenu()
    for x in items{
        let item = NSMenuItem()
        item.title = x.title
        item.target = x // If I remove this line or the line below, there won't be any crash
        item.action = #selector(MenuItem.doAction) 
        item.image = x.iconName.toImage()
        m.addItem(item)
    }

    return m
}
```

Now my problem is whenever the contextual menu is shown, the program crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

However, when I comment out the line that sets the target or the action, then the problem will be gone (the menu then won't be clickable of course).

So how do I fix this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I should have stated that I already tried these things:

1. Using #selector(x.doAction) rather than #selector(MenuItem.doAction)
2. Using #selector(x.doAction(sender:))

Also, there is nothing in the output window. That's why I'm seeking help here. Worse, it involves EXC_BAD_ACCESS which I can hardly grasp given that memory is supposed to be managed by the system.

Comment: Change `#selector(MenuItem.doAction)` to `#selector(x.doAction)`

Comment: There should be an error message in console when it crash. I guess that it should be "-[ProjectName.MenuItem doAction] unrecognized selector sent to instance" or something like that. Remove the `#selector(MenuItem.doAction)`, and write it again letting completion help you. The signature of the method is wrong, because you accept a param (`sender:`) which is not present in your current selector. Also shouldn't you write `let item = MenuItem()` instead of `let item = NSMenuItem()`?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I tried that already. Read my edits. Thanks.

Comment: @Larme There's no output at all. Also, MenuItem is my abstraction of NSMenuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the `items` inside the array I'm passing to the static `getMenu` function are being deallocated after the getMenu function is complete (which is very soon followed by the `popUpMenuWithEvent:forView`).

I solved it by having a strong reference to that array.